# Swift: Making a swift Dictionary with a list of vertices and convert it to JSON

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to make a dictionary for my captured data. I have read the swift document regarding writing a simply dictionary for one or two key-value pairs. However, my captured data look like this:

[image]

That's what I have for the JSON strcut

```
struct CaptureData {
    var vertices: [SIMD3<Float>]

    var verticesFormatted : String {
        let vertices_x = vertices.map{ "\($0.x)"}
        let vertices_y = vertices.map{ "\($0.y)"}
        let vertices_z = vertices.map{ "\($0.z)"}
            return "\(vertices_x)\(vertices_y)\(vertices_z)"
        }
    var jsonDict: [String : Any] =
        [
               "facetracking_data" : [
                "info" : [

                    "time_collected" : Date().timeIntervalSince1970
                ],
                "data" : [
                    "frame" : 0,
                    "timestamp" : 12343425,
                    "vertices" : [
                        "x": 0.1,
                        "y": 0.2,
                        "z": 0.3
                        ]
                ]
           ]
    ]
```

How can I make a swift Dictionary with a list of vertices and convert it to my defined JSON

### Updates

I followed Koen's suggestion to get the struct from QuickType.

```
//   let facetrackingDemoData = try? newJSONDecoder().decode(FacetrackingDemoData.self, from: jsonData)

import Foundation

// MARK: - FacetrackingDemoData
struct FacetrackingDemoData: Codable {
    let facetrackingData: FacetrackingData

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case facetrackingData = "facetracking_data"
    }
}

// MARK: - FacetrackingData
struct FacetrackingData: Codable {
    let info: Info
    let data: [Datum]
}

// MARK: - Datum
struct Datum: Codable {
    let frame, timestamp: Int
    let verticies: [Verticy]
}

// MARK: - Verticy
struct Verticy: Codable {
    let vertex: Int
    let x, y, z: Double
}

// MARK: - Info
struct Info: Codable {
    let timeCollected: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case timeCollected = "time_collected"
    }
}
```

Comment: The idea is to make your datamodel mirror your required json structure. Then you can convert between the two using the `Codable` protocol. If you know what your json should look like, you can enter it at https://app.quicktype.io and it will create a data model that you can use.

Comment: Please do not repeat questions if you don't get an answer on the other one.

Comment: Thanks for the repsonse! I enter the JSON file to app.quicktype.io and create the code. I am assuming that I can use that for calling the JSON strcut. Could you explain how that does help if I want to put the capture into the dictionary?

Comment: Please add the code from quicktype in your question (not in the comments).

Comment: I uploaded that! Thanks for your time!

Comment: To create JSON from your data, just go the other way around: `let json = try? JSONEncoder().encode(FacetrackingDemoData)`

Comment: Should I put that in an new script for this? (not Viewcontroller?) I am a bit confused on this. I saw the pokemon example where they put the the Pokedex into a new script and then they have the API to call back? For my class is that I only have the captured streaming data and I don't have a API

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by new script. Wherever you want to convert the data depends on the structure of your application. Inside a ViewController could work.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Could you guide me a bit? So I would put that struct into my Viewcontroller. And could I parse my captured data to that struct? is it because of the let facetrackingDemoData = try? newJSONDecoder().decode(FacetrackingDemoData.self, from: jsonData)

Comment: Please post a new question specifically describing your new problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I think its still the same question. When I put the code to ViewController, I am just wondering how does this dictionary help me to get the list of those vertices